# Mostrar o tempo de execução de um Algorítmo em milissegundos em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testes

Até agora só achei perguntas que mostre segundos. Eu gostaria de achar em Milissegundos.

Segue o código que tentei:

```
import time 
start = time.time()

def firstDuplicate(a):
    dic={}
    for x in a:
        if(x in dic):
            return x
        dic[x]=1
    return -1

firstDuplicate([1,2,2])


print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start))
```

Comment: Eu usei um `profiler` para ter (entre outras coisas) uma medida do tempo consumido pelo programa. `import profile; profile.run("my_function()")`

Comment: De segundos para milissegundos, basta dividir por 1000. Não tem muito segredo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode calcular de forma mais precisa o tempo de execução de uma determinada operação por amostragem.

Você repete a mesma operação por `N` vezes e calcula o tempo total gasto, com isso, você é capaz de calcular o tempo médio que a operação em teste demora para ser concluída.

```
from datetime import datetime

# Quantidade de amostras
n = 1000000;

# Funcao em teste
def firstDuplicate(a):
    dic={}
    for x in a:
        if(x in dic):
            return x
        dic[x]=1
    return -1

# Registra o momento antes do teste
t0 = datetime.now()

# Repete a operacao em teste por N vezes...
for i in range( n ):

    # Operacoes em teste
    firstDuplicate([1,2,2])
    firstDuplicate([1,2,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17])

# Registra o momento apos teste
t1 = datetime.now()

# Calcula o tempo de execucao das N operacoes executadas
diff = t1 - t0

# Calcula a media de tempo de execucao em milissegundos de cada operacao
med = (diff.total_seconds() * 1000) / n

# Exibe resultado do teste
print( "Tempo da operacao: " + str(med) + " ms" )
```

Saída:

```
Tempo da operacao: 0.002130244 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muita pesquisa, muita documentação dos módulos adicionais, e pesquisas em outros Stackoverflows cheguei a minha resposta.

Em `Estrutura de Dados` fazemos a `Análise Assintótica de Algoritmos`, no caso verificados o melhor caso `O(1)` e os outros casos.

De fato essa é a melhor maneira de observar o comportamento de um algoritmo e ver como ele se comporta baseado no número de comparações que ele faz.

Esse é o jeito humano de fazer comparações de Algoritmos.

Agora, existe `Estruturas de Dados` que são ou chegam perto do O(1), a estrutura `Hash` em especial, pois usa uma chave única em vez de vasculhar toda uma lista. Ou existe ou não existe, não existe a dúvida.

Em Python temos a Estrutura Hash se baseando em dois tipos: `Dicionários e Conjuntos`

Qualquer consulta feita nessas estruturas vai ser O(1), e isso torna o Algoritmo muito rápido.

De fato, o Algoritmo se torna tão rápido que sua execução não chega a ser nem em microssegundos(testei em código e isso foi confirmado).

Agora começa os empecilhos: A maioria dos Sistemas Operacionais só conseguem garantir precisão de no máximo **1 segundo**, passou disso há risco até de valores absurdos(o valor de um tempo medido depois ser menor que o valor do tempo medido antes).A máquina não consegue expressar nanossegundos, o que torna a medição de Algoritmos rápidos algo impossível.A contagem de tempo de um Algoritmo vai depender do que está acontecendo com a máquina naquele momento.

Portanto, tristemente, o melhor jeito de medir o tempo de execução do Algoritmo é através da análise assintótica.

Segue o código que tentei em Nanossegundos.

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.now()
antes = dt.microsecond


def firstDuplicate(a):
    dic={}
    for x in a:
        if(x in dic):
            return x
        dic[x]=1
    return -1

firstDuplicate([1,2,2])
print(firstDuplicate([1,2,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]))
ps = datetime.now()
depois = ps.microsecond
print("Microsegundos:")
print(depois-antes)
```